# Slow click handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mustache

```
$(document).ready(function() {

loadElementsWithSubmitButton();

    $(document).on('click', '.submit_button', function() {
        alert("Took more than 5 seconds to get here...");
        return false;
    });
});
```

So I have this piece of code. `.submit_button` refers to about 800 button elements. And when I click one of those 800 buttons, it takes a while for the code to jump to the click handler function. Why is this and what can I do to fix it??

**UPDATE:** So it appears what's causing the button to be slow is that the button is being generated in a mustache template, but if I don't generate it with the template, it's fast. Any ideas why this is happening?

**SOLVED:** Apparently, it was a class within my template that caused the button press to be slow.. Weird..

Comment: Why is the event delegated to the `document`?

Comment: You have 800 submit buttons? Would love to see a screenshot. Also would suggest analyzing the memory usage of your JavaScript.

Comment: Damned near instantaneous here: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/TSrpZ/

Comment: @tymeJV - because as the docs say, "In addition to their ability to handle events on descendant elements not yet created, another advantage of delegated events is their potential for much lower overhead when many elements must be monitored. "

Comment: @tymeJV as apposed to creating 800 event handlers on each button? What's the alternative? This seems like the right approach (though 800 buttons on any UI is probably excessive)

Comment: No, as opposed to just binding a handler to the `submit_button` class?

Comment: @j08691 -- Didn't know that about many elements...thanks.

Comment: @j08691: It's only inefficient if you're using jQuery, because jQuery needs to create a new event handler for every element bound, even if all the elements get the same handler you've provided. When direct binding without jQuery, one could bind the same function, and it would be very efficient.

Comment: @user2736012 - why are you telling me? It was tymeJV who asked.

Comment: @j08691: Because I'm responding to your comment. Delegating to the `document` should rarely be done, and the lower overhead is only compared to direct binding with jQuery.

Comment: 5 seconds? i have tried your jsFiddle in my chrome browser, result: less than 1 second... what is your setup?